# Looping through Multiple JSON Objects in Android

Tags: java, android, json

I'm trying to parse a JSON object, part of which looks like this :

```
{
  "status":{
  "rcode":200,
  "message":"OK"
},
"data":{
   "0":{
     "SubFranchiseID":"0",
     "OutletID":"607",
     "OutletName":"Spill ",
     "BrandID":"403",
     "Address":"J-349, JP Road, Opp. Apna Bazar, JP Rd, D.N.Nagar, Andheri West, Mumbai, Maharashtra, India",
     "NeighbourhoodID":"1",
     "CityID":"1",
     "Email":null,
     "Timings":"Everyday: 6 pm to 1:30 am.",
     "CityRank":null,
     "Latitude":"19.127473",
     "Longitude":"72.832545",
     "Pincode":null,
     "Landmark":null,
     "Streetname":null,
     "BrandName":"Spill ",
     "OutletURL":"https:\/\/plus.google.com\/111539701326240643109\/about?hl=en-US",
     "NumCoupons":1,
     "NeighbourhoodName":"Andheri West",
     "PhoneNumber":"+91 22 2642 5895",
     "CityName":"Mumbai",
     "Distance":8205.2235,
     "Categories":[
        {
           "OfflineCategoryID":"32",
           "Name":"Continental",
           "ParentCategoryID":"1",
           "CategoryType":"Cuisine"
        },
        {
           "OfflineCategoryID":"13",
           "Name":"Bar and Restaurant",
           "ParentCategoryID":"1",
           "CategoryType":"TypeOfRestaurant"
        },
        {
           "OfflineCategoryID":"17",
           "Name":"Italian",
           "ParentCategoryID":"1",
           "CategoryType":"Cuisine"
        },
        {
           "OfflineCategoryID":"1",
           "Name":"Restaurant",
           "ParentCategoryID":null,
           "CategoryType":""
        },
        {
           "OfflineCategoryID":"21",
           "Name":"North Indian",
           "ParentCategoryID":"1",
           "CategoryType":"Cuisine"
        }
     ],
     "LogoURL":"http:\/\/www.google.in\/sitespecific\/media\/generated\/offlineimages\/logo_403.jpg",
     "CoverURL":"http:\/\/www.google.in\/sitespecific\/media\/generated\/offlineimages\/cover_607.jpg"
  },
 "1 "{
      "SubFranchiseID":"1",
     "OutletID":"60",
     "OutletName":"Bill ",
       .
       .
       .
      }
}
```

There are nearly 35 Json objects and nested JsonArrays for each of these objects.I'm trying to get data like this :

```
  url = new URL(uri);
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }

        reader.close();
        json =sb.toString();
        JSONObject sjson=json.getJSONObject("data");
        Log.d("sjson values-->",sjson+"--");
        **JSONObject ssjson=sjson.getJSONObject("0");**
```

And now i am getting each of values like this :

```
String outletName = ssjson.getString("OutletName");
```

My question is there any better way (loop) through all objects ( 0,1,...35) and get data for each individual object separately.

Comment: You should be using gson that writing all the boiler plate json parsing yourself. That being said, please atleast put up the exact json that you expect in the response,that is valid as this seems to be invalid json structure.

Comment: i have edited the json data and i tried to use **Iterator<?> keys = resobj.keys();** ande iterate keys through while loop. Android Studio is unable to convert json to Java Object class due to the names "0" of json data.Can you give give insight on how to parse using Gson

Answer (score 0):

**Example json**

```
{
    "status": {
        "rcode": "200",
        "message": "Good, you got me!!!"
    },
    "data": [
        {
            "SubFranchiseID": "0",
            "OutletID": "607",
            "OutletName": "Spill",

        },
        {
            "SubFranchiseID": "0",
            "OutletID": "607",
            "OutletName": "Spill"
        }
    ]
}
```

> Represent the json in terms of plain java classes with getter and
>   setters

**First create a the root class (for the root object)**

```
public class Root {
  //For the status object
  private Status status;
  //For the array of data objects
  private List<Data> data;

  //create setters and getters for the two properties.
}

public class Status {

  private String rcode; 
  //this maps to the rcode in the status object in json
  private String message;
  //create setters and getters for the two
}

public class Data {
  private String SubFranchiseID;
  private String OutletID;
  private String OutletName;

//create setters and getters for these properties.
}
```

**Now, lets do the magic with gson (The serialization of the json in to the ready made classes)**

```
reader.close();
json =sb.toString();

Root root = new Gson().fromJson(response, Root.class);
//get the rcode
if(root.getStatus().getrCode().equalsIgnoreCase("200"))
 {
   //print the data.
   for(Data d : root.getData()) {
      System.out.println(d.getSubFranchiseID()+"-"+d.getOutletID()+"-"+d.getOutletName());

   }
 }
```

> A small note for using gson.

```
 1.)  The property names inside the classes should match the property in the json or else use a `@SerializeName("propertyname")`.

 2.)  An array of objects would map to List<YourObject> , for eg : the data property in the json.

 3.)  You can have default value for your properties without creating getters and setters for them like 

private boolean isJson = true;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have a lot of json objects inside "data" -> "0" like  "Outletname","OutletID ",etc , before Json Array ( "Categories" ). i have created a model class for my data. Now i want to itterate json objects data using Gson .

Comment: That's simple..You see the for loop that i have written , thats the way to iterate over the data.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. I have a lot of json objects inside "data" -> "0" like  "Outletname","OutletID ",etc , before Json Array ( "Categories" ). i have created a model class for my data. Now i want to itterate json objects data using Gson.Part of my json data

```
  "0":{
 "SubFranchiseID":"0",
 "OutletID":"607",
 "OutletName":"Spill ",
 "BrandID":"403",
 "Address":"J-349, JP Road, Opp. Apna Bazar, JP Rd, D.N.Nagar, Andheri West, Mumbai, Maharashtra, India",
 "NeighbourhoodID":"1",
 "CityID":"1",
 "Email":null,
 "Timings":"Everyday: 6 pm to 1:30 am.",
 "CityRank":null,
 "Latitude":"19.127473",
 "Longitude":"72.832545",
 "Pincode":null,
 "Landmark":null,
 "Streetname":null,
 "BrandName":"Spill ",
 "OutletURL":"https:\/\/plus.google.com\/111539701326240643109\/about?hl=en-US",
 "NumCoupons":1,
 "NeighbourhoodName":"Andheri West",
 "PhoneNumber":"+91 22 2642 5895",
 "CityName":"Mumbai",
 "Distance":8205.2235,
 "Categories":[
    {
       "OfflineCategoryID":"32",
       "Name":"Continental",
       "ParentCategoryID":"1",
       "CategoryType":"Cuisine"
    },
    {
       "OfflineCategoryID":"13",
       "Name":"Bar and Restaurant",
       "ParentCategoryID":"1",
       "CategoryType":"TypeOfRestaurant"
    },
    {
       "OfflineCategoryID":"17",
       "Name":"Italian",
       "ParentCategoryID":"1",
       "CategoryType":"Cuisine"
    },
    {
       "OfflineCategoryID":"1",
       "Name":"Restaurant",
       "ParentCategoryID":null,
       "CategoryType":""
    },
    {
       "OfflineCategoryID":"21",
       "Name":"North Indian",
       "ParentCategoryID":"1",
       "CategoryType":"Cuisine"
    }
 ],
 "LogoURL":"http:\/\/www.google.in\/sitespecific\/media\/generated\/offlineimages\/logo_403.jpg",
 "CoverURL":"http:\/\/www.google.in\/sitespecific\/media\/generated\/offlineimages\/cover_607.jpg"
 },
}
```

My java Model Class :

```
        /**
         * SubFranchiseID : 0
         * OutletID : 607
         * OutletName : Spill
         * BrandID : 403
         * Address : J-349, JP Road, Opp. Apna Bazar, JP Rd,     D.N.Nagar, Andheri West, Mumbai, Maharashtra, India
         * NeighbourhoodID : 1
         * CityID : 1
         * Email : null
         * Timings : Everyday: 6 pm to 1:30 am.
         * CityRank : null
         * Latitude : 19.127473
         * Longitude : 72.832545
         * Pincode : null
         * Landmark : null
         * Streetname : null
         * BrandName : Spill
         * OutletURL : https://plus.google.com/111539701326240643109/about?hl=en-US
         * NumCoupons : 1
         * NeighbourhoodName : Andheri West
         * PhoneNumber : +91 22 2642 5895
         * CityName : Mumbai
         * Distance : 8205.2235
         * Categories : [{"OfflineCategoryID":"32","Name":"Continental","ParentCategoryID":"1","CategoryType":"Cuisine"},{"OfflineCategoryID":"13","Name":"Bar and Restaurant","ParentCategoryID":"1","CategoryType":"TypeOfRestaurant"},{"OfflineCategoryID":"17","Name":"Italian","ParentCategoryID":"1","CategoryType":"Cuisine"},{"OfflineCategoryID":"1","Name":"Restaurant","ParentCategoryID":null,"CategoryType":""},{"OfflineCategoryID":"21","Name":"North Indian","ParentCategoryID":"1","CategoryType":"Cuisine"}]
         * LogoURL : http://www.google.in/sitespecific/media/generated/offlineimages/logo_403.jpg
         * CoverURL : http://www.google.in/sitespecific/media/generated/offlineimages/cover_607.jpg
         */
public static class OutletDetailsEntity {
        private String SubFranchiseID;
        private String OutletID;
        private String OutletName;
        private String BrandID;
        private String Address;
        private String NeighbourhoodID;
        private String CityID;
        private Object Email;
        private String Timings;
        private Object CityRank;
        private String Latitude;
        private String Longitude;
        private Object Pincode;
        private Object Landmark;
        private Object Streetname;
        private String BrandName;
        private String OutletURL;
        private int NumCoupons;
        private String NeighbourhoodName;
        private String PhoneNumber;
        private String CityName;
        private double Distance;
        private String LogoURL;
        private String CoverURL;
        private List<CategoriesEntity> Categories;

        public void setSubFranchiseID(String SubFranchiseID) {
            this.SubFranchiseID = SubFranchiseID;
        }

        public void setOutletID(String OutletID) {
            this.OutletID = OutletID;
        }

        public void setOutletName(String OutletName) {
            this.OutletName = OutletName;
        }

        public void setBrandID(String BrandID) {
            this.BrandID = BrandID;
        }

        public void setAddress(String Address) {
            this.Address = Address;
        }

        public void setNeighbourhoodID(String NeighbourhoodID) {
            this.NeighbourhoodID = NeighbourhoodID;
        }

        public void setCityID(String CityID) {
            this.CityID = CityID;
        }

        public void setEmail(Object Email) {
            this.Email = Email;
        }

        public void setTimings(String Timings) {
            this.Timings = Timings;
        }

        public void setCityRank(Object CityRank) {
            this.CityRank = CityRank;
        }

        public void setLatitude(String Latitude) {
            this.Latitude = Latitude;
        }

        public void setLongitude(String Longitude) {
            this.Longitude = Longitude;
        }

        public void setPincode(Object Pincode) {
            this.Pincode = Pincode;
        }

        public void setLandmark(Object Landmark) {
            this.Landmark = Landmark;
        }

        public void setStreetname(Object Streetname) {
            this.Streetname = Streetname;
        }

        public void setBrandName(String BrandName) {
            this.BrandName = BrandName;
        }

        public void setOutletURL(String OutletURL) {
            this.OutletURL = OutletURL;
        }

        public void setNumCoupons(int NumCoupons) {
            this.NumCoupons = NumCoupons;
        }

        public void setNeighbourhoodName(String NeighbourhoodName) {
            this.NeighbourhoodName = NeighbourhoodName;
        }

        public void setPhoneNumber(String PhoneNumber) {
            this.PhoneNumber = PhoneNumber;
        }

        public void setCityName(String CityName) {
            this.CityName = CityName;
        }

        public void setDistance(double Distance) {
            this.Distance = Distance;
        }

        public void setLogoURL(String LogoURL) {
            this.LogoURL = LogoURL;
        }

        public void setCoverURL(String CoverURL) {
            this.CoverURL = CoverURL;
        }

        public void setCategories(List<CategoriesEntity> Categories) {
            this.Categories = Categories;
        }

        public String getSubFranchiseID() {
            return SubFranchiseID;
        }

        public String getOutletID() {
            return OutletID;
        }

        public String getOutletName() {
            return OutletName;
        }

        public String getBrandID() {
            return BrandID;
        }

        public String getAddress() {
            return Address;
        }

        public String getNeighbourhoodID() {
            return NeighbourhoodID;
        }

        public String getCityID() {
            return CityID;
        }

        public Object getEmail() {
            return Email;
        }

        public String getTimings() {
            return Timings;
        }

        public Object getCityRank() {
            return CityRank;
        }

        public String getLatitude() {
            return Latitude;
        }

        public String getLongitude() {
            return Longitude;
        }

        public Object getPincode() {
            return Pincode;
        }

        public Object getLandmark() {
            return Landmark;
        }

        public Object getStreetname() {
            return Streetname;
        }

        public String getBrandName() {
            return BrandName;
        }

        public String getOutletURL() {
            return OutletURL;
        }

        public int getNumCoupons() {
            return NumCoupons;
        }

        public String getNeighbourhoodName() {
            return NeighbourhoodName;
        }

        public String getPhoneNumber() {
            return PhoneNumber;
        }

        public String getCityName() {
            return CityName;
        }

        public double getDistance() {
            return Distance;
        }

        public String getLogoURL() {
            return LogoURL;
        }

        public String getCoverURL() {
            return CoverURL;
        }
```